# Honda Civic hybrid won’t start with new battery

Tags: honda, battery, starting, civic, hybrid

I have a 2007 Honda Civic hybrid that I just got a new battery put in. After the battery was placed in my car I was able to drive home. The next day when I went to start my car everything went black as if my battery had died again but when I just leave the key in the ignition all the functions work fine. It’s just until I actually try to start the car.

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue???

Comment: Have you checked the battery cables?  A loose or dirty connection would have these exact symptoms.

Comment: I think @mike65535  may be on the right track here ... not having to do with your hybrid battery, but the regular 12v battery in the car. The 12v battery runs all of the "normal" stuff in your car. You may try putting a multimeter on the 12v to see what the voltage reads.

Comment: I will try that out and get back to you